# The shorter code to insert data from Python into Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

I need to insert data from Python into Oracle. My table in Oracle has about 30 columns. I would like to know if there is a way to use the shorter code in next 3 cases.

**case 1**

Only 30 columns in `my_table` and 30 values in data

```py
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.executemany('''
insert into my_table 
values (:1,:2,...,:30)
''', data)
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

**case 2**

30 columns + 1 column with default `sysdate` in `my_table` and 30 values in data

```py
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.executemany('''
insert into my_table 
(col1, col2,..., col30)
values (:1,:2,...,:30)
''', data)
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

**case 3**

30 columns in `my_table` and 10 values in data

```py
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.executemany('''
insert into my_table 
(col1, col2,..., col10)
values (:1,:2,...,:10)
''', data)
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

Is there a way not to list all 30 columns?
Something like `values(:)` for case 1 or `values(:1 - :10)` for case 3
How can I specify all columns except default `sysdate` in case 2?

Comment: You should _always_ explicitly list out the columns in a SQL insert statement.  Even if you could do what you are suggesting, the logic could break later on if the order of the columns in the target table were to change.  So, I vote for leaving your code as is.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about listing numbers in values? I think it is not a very efficient way. Can I use something like `values(:)`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible/desirable either.  But, as you already have seen, you may _bind_ a Python list or tuple to the statement.  So, at least that gives you some savings in lines of code.

Comment: Great! I didn't think about it... I can also use the dictionary instead of arrays and give names to columns in Oracle the same as the dictionary's keys. So there will be the same tuple for values and columns.

Comment: Optimize for correctness and performance, not for shorter code.  One tip: instead of the overhead of a round-trip that `con.commit()` will require, considering using [autocommit](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/txn_management.html#autocommitting)  but don't commit unnecessarily.